# The expression $2 \sin3x \cos3x = \sin kx$, find the value of $k$

Tags: angle

I am supposed to use double angle identity, however, I cant seem to fit any of the equations. I tried saying that the first part of the equation is sin(2x), but I don`t understand why that is incorrect, as $sinx*cosx*2=sin(2x)$. Therefore k would be equal to 2, but the correct answer is supposed to be 6.

Comment: Let's say $y=3x$, you obtain $\sin(2y)$ first, then substitute to get $\sin(2\cdot 3x)=\sin(6x)$, $k=6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sin(3x)\cos(3x)=\sin(6x)$$ so $$\sin(6x)=\sin(kx)$$ Then you can use $$2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)=0$$

Comment: I just don`t understand why it is $sin(6x)$, what did you multiply or do to get there?